# Difference between majorant, minorant and convex envelopes?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I have been reading "Convex Analysis and Global Optimization 2016" a Book by Hoang Tuy and stumble upon these terms: majorant, minorant.

Does this **concave majorant** have the simirlar implication of the concave upper bound or something ?

Furthermore, the authors seem to use the term covex minorant and concave majorant together, does this mean they present the same geometric structure ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $m$ is a *minorant* (resp. *majorant*) of $f$ if, for every $x$ in your space $\mathcal{X}$, $m(x)\leq f(x)$ (resp. $m(x)\geq f(x)$).

It is common to find a minorant of a convex function, since many convex functions are not bounded above. These notions frequently appear in [MM algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MM_algorithm). Also, if you restrict to the set of affine minorants, this is closely related to notions of the [subgradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative#The_subgradient) of $f$.

The *convex envelope* of $f$, usually denoted $f^{**}$ is produced by taking the [Legendre dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Definition) twice. This function is always a convex, lower-semicontinuous minorant of $f$, even if $f$ was not originally convex. Some view the convex envelope as the "closest" function to $f$ which is also convex and lower-semicontinuous.

If you multiply everything by $-1$, the geometry is almost analogous for concave majorants.

Comment: Thank you this is so insightful, especially the part about the Majorization Minimization Algorithm

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh happy to help!